Brother b-PAC SDK Very slow to open template and end print
I use .NET Framework 4.8
I have a Label API where I use b-PAC SDK to print to label printer.
In this case let's say 5 people print to the same label printer with same template at max 10 sec between each other.
But Open() and EndPrint() takes forever sometime even in total 50 minutes to finish.
In this case Open() method take 40 seconds and EndPrint() method take 50 seconds to finish.
That means this printing request to my label API take around 2 minutes to print.
I have many cases where it goes over 30 minutes in total.
See logging for this example:

public void Print(string printer, string label, int copyCount, Settings settings, ILogger _logger) {
    bpac.DocumentClass doc = new bpac.DocumentClass();

    using (ITimer timer = _logger.Time("Open Template")) {
        if (!doc.Open(string.Format(_pathTemaplate, label))) {
            throw new Exception("Document couldn't be opened");
        }
    }

    using (ITimer timer = _logger.Time("Set Printer")) {
        if (!doc.SetPrinter("{printer}", false)) {
            throw new Exception("Couldn't set printer");
        }
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in settings.Data) {
        bpac.IObject field = doc.GetObject(kv.Key);
        if (field == null) {
            continue;
        }
        field.Text = kv.Value;
    }

    PrintOptionConstants options = PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault;

    try {
        using (ITimer timer = _logger.Time("Start Print")) {
            doc.StartPrint(label, options);
        }

        using (ITimer timer = _logger.Time("Printing")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < copyCount; i++) {
                doc.PrintOut(1, options);
            }
        }

        using (ITimer timer = _logger.Time("End Print")) {
            doc.EndPrint();
        }

    }
    finally {
        using (ITimer timer = _logger.Time("Close document")) {
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}


got slower on Open() and SetPrinter() after moving away from local servers to the cloud.
I used a 32 bit Delphi software for 5 years and noticed various delays for some user.
Even the P-touch 5.4 are sloooow, to start 30 sec.
Locking for a solution.
